# Most performant way to verify an element exists in a given set in C++

Tags: c++, performance, set, hashset

I've been trying to write a code that finds all the numbers which summed to its inverted counterpart would result in an odd number, as for "12 + 21 = 33", "605839 + 938506 = 1544345", and so on and so forth...

I've reached the problem of accessing the values of a given unordered_set and checking if a value is within it or not. The problem is the performance of the said "check", as for some reason that I can't identify, this verification is absurdly slow the way I did it, it seems the time grows exponentially the bigger the number of elements in the given set is.

I would like to create a set, or a list of elements that doesn't repeat its values, which can access and insert elements in the most performatic way, disregarding the order of the elements, as the order doesn't really matter for this implementation.

This is the code a came up with

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    string invertSequence(string sequence);

    int main() 
    {
        unordered_set <int> control;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            string number = std::to_string(i);
            string invertedSequence = invertSequence(number);
            int invertedNumber = stoi(invertedSequence);
            int sumValue = i + invertedNumber;
            if (!control.count(invertedNumber) && number.at(number.length() - 1) != '0') {
                control.insert(i);
                if (sumValue % 2 != 0) {
                    cout << i << " + " << invertedNumber << " = " << i + invertedNumber << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    string invertSequence(string sequence) 
    {
        char inverted[sequence.length()];
        const char* charSequence = sequence.c_str();
        for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); i++) 
        {
            inverted[sequence.length() -i - 1] = charSequence[i];
        }

        return inverted;
    }
```

I made the same code in Java, and it runs pretty good, it calculates all the ocurrences between 0 and 1 million in around 3800 milliseconds, whereas in my C++ code I never really let it run until the end, because its too slow and would take an eternity.

Java has the HashSet class which does this job pretty well. Here is my java code [Impl](https://github.com/jupiterise/coolLittleCodes/blob/main/findInvertedNumbersWhichTheSumIsOdd.java).

I've searched the internet and read that unordered_set in C++ is similar to HashSet in Java, but maybe I'm missing out on something, cause the performance of both is way too different the way I'm doing it.

I'd appreciate any help in this matter!

Comment: Ummm..... all you have to do is check the first and last digits. The sum is odd if (`firstDigit is odd` xor `last digit is odd`)

Comment: 1.) Are you compiling with optimizations on? 2.) Are you sure it's the unordered_set access which is slow, and not the printing to the console every iteration in your loop?

Comment: Regarding #2, if I take your exact code and [swap out](https://godbolt.org/z/q8Wj9bxMd) the print statement for incrementing a counter, it runs in well under a second.

Comment: *"this verification is absurdly slow the way I did it"* -- how did you determine this? A better question would isolate the verification (drop the other processing; don't worry about what your real goal is) and focus on timing how slow it is.

Comment: By any chance, does the performance improve if you null-terminate `inverted` before converting it to a `std::string`? Undefined behavior is allowed to manifest slow performance.

Comment: @JaMiT - If you post that last comment in the form of an answer, I will upvote it.  You've hit the nail on the head - that string doesn't get zero terminated, so it could be just about any length.  Presumably, calling `stoi` on it usually deals with whatever garbage characters may be present; but there's no guarantee of this.  This looks like a potential functional bug, not just a performance issue.

Comment: Haven't looked at run times yet, but `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, include the entire freaking C++ Standard Library, is utter murder on build times unless you use it correctly, and using it alongside string and iostream suggests you aren't using it correctly.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Meh, seems more like a "typo that would not help future readers" to me, given how the question is so emphatic about the problem being in the call to `control.count()` (a.k.a. checking if a value is in the set).

Comment: @JaMiT Yeah, you're probably right.  I just feel sorry for people who are coming along, reading the question, and not picking up on the lack of zero termination in `invertSequence`.  It would be nice to have an answer with a big green tick next to it.

Comment: @JaMiT this is why the key to performance tuning is benchmarking.  Intuition is never a good way to figure out where your slowness comes from, you need to measure it.

Comment: That probably explains why when I made small tweaks to `invertSequence` I got different output for the total number in my code. Replacing `charSequence[i]` with `sequence[i]` got different results, but then `sequence.at(i)` got the same ones...Undefined behavior hooray.

Comment: `bool fasttest(std::uint64_t const x){for(auto y=x;y>9;y%=10); return (y+x)&1;};` use this as the perdicate to find the numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @JaMiT recognized, it's not the set that's the problem; it's the potentially unterminated C string. If you invert into another `std::string`, which knows its length, you won't run into that problem:

```cpp
string invertSequence(string sequence) 
{
  string inverted(' ', sequence.size());
  for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); i++) 
    {
      inverted[sequence.length() - i - 1] = sequence[i];
    }
  return inverted;
}
```

and at least on my computer, it runs in about 0.6 seconds.

Finally, of course, `std::reverse` is shorter, safer, and even a little faster:

```cpp
string invertSequence(string sequence) 
{
  reverse(sequence.begin(), sequence.end());
  return sequence;
}
```

Comment: yeah, the inversion with that for statement was increasing the time by A LOT